# How to change Datagrid row color at runtime in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am using WPF DataGrid and adding rows at runtime by using a class RowItem

```
 public class RowItem //Class
 {
     public int Rule_ID { get; set; }
     public string Rule_Desc { get; set; }
     public Int64 Count_Of_Failure { get; set; }
 }    

adding row at run time like :

dgValidateRules.Items.Add(new RowItem() { Rule_ID = ruleID, Rule_Desc = ruleDesc, Count_Of_Failure = ttlHodlings });
```

Used the below Loading Row event code for changing color of the datagrid row.  But its not working.

```
private void dgValidateRules_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 1; i < dgValidateRules.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    if (((RowItem)dgValidateRules.Items[i]).Count_Of_Failure == 0)
      e.Row.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    else
      e.Row.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
  }
}
```

Can anybody tell me the solution?

Comment: Wooow just look at your question....do you expect that anyone will bother to read that mess? Please format your question before posting.

Comment: What do you want to change exactly.? background color of the row or the Foreground color.? Note that Foreground color will change the text color.

Comment: Yes i need to change just text color.

Answer (score 0):

Because it row event there it is the worng place to do it, here you can place a condition about the row:

```
    private void table_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((MyData)e.Row.DataContext).Module.Trim().Equals("SomeText"))
        {
            e.Row.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with a [DataTrigger](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/) or [Converter](https://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemsSource}">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow"> 
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Count_Of_Failure}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Count_Of_Failure}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```